# How to return a Numeric Agtype in Apache AGE

Tags: apache-age

I'm trying to write a function named age_trunc.
For Now all I want to do is for that function to return empty Numeric Agtype.

I've done:

```
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(age_trunc);

Datum age_trunc(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{

    agtype_value agtv_result;  
    
    agtv_result.type = AGTV_NUMERIC;
    agtv_result.val.numeric= 0;

    PG_RETURN_POINTER(agtype_value_to_agtype(&agtv_result));
}
```

With this my Postgres Crashes.

When i do :

```
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(age_trunc);

Datum age_trunc(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{

    agtype_value agtv_result;  
    
    agtv_result.type = AGTV_FLOAT;
    agtv_result.val.float_value= 0;

    PG_RETURN_POINTER(agtype_value_to_agtype(&agtv_result));
}
```

Everything works fine and I get the desired output which is 0.0

Can anyone help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following line:

```
 agtv_result.val.numeric = DatumGetNumeric(DirectFunctionCall1(
     int8_numeric, Int64GetDatum(0)));
```

This is a numeric 0 as a datum

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create a Numeric type value. Keep in mind that  Numeric values can be both `int` or `float`, so you have to call the appropriate function instead.

Here is the code for `int8_numeric`:

```
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(age_trunc);

Datum age_trunc(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{

    agtype_value agtv_result;

    Numeric numeric_value = DatumGetNumeric(DirectFunctionCall1(int8_numeric, Int64GetDatum(0)));

    agtv_result.type = AGTV_NUMERIC;
    agtv_result.val.numeric = numeric_value;

    PG_RETURN_POINTER(agtype_value_to_agtype(&agtv_result));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to typecast the value to a numeric value. Therefore, instead of

```
agtv_result.val.numeric= 0;
```

it should be:

```
agtv_result.val.numeric= DatumGetNumeric(DirectFunctionCall1(int8_numeric, Int64GetDatum(0)));
```